# ASP.NET Core error on building with NSwag Error MSB3073

Tags: asp.net-core, nswag

When I build the application, I get the following error message

```
The command "dotnet "C:\Users\Adminuser\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.0.6\build\../tools/NetCore22/dotnet-nswag.dll" run /variables:Configuration=Debug" exited with code
-2147450730.    Northwind.WebUI C:\Users\Adminuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NorthwindTraders-master\Northwind.WebUI\Northwind.WebUI.csproj 60
```

Any Idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please read [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Swagger doesn't like it when two or more endpoints in the same Controller share the same name. make use of routing attributes and make sure they are unique.

Answer (score 1):

NSwag fails when two methods of the same controller share the same **HTTP GET** (or **HTTP POST**) verb without setting an explicit *Route* in one of them:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Test1()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(1);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Test2")] // <-----< This line is important! <-----<
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Test2()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(2);
    }
}
```

Without the `[Route("Test2")]`  line, I get a *System.InvalidOperationException: The method 'get' on path '/api/Test' is registered multiple times.* error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [NSwagStudio](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio) then re open your visual studio.
That's should solve your problem.

**If it's still not working**

give a look about your output console when you try to compile your project, you should see something like this

> 1>Executing file 'nswag.json' with variables 'Configuration=Debug'...
>   1>Launcher directory:
>   C:\Users\Shadow.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.1.6\tools\NetCore30

You should have a file called ***dotnet-nswag.exe*** in your *c:\user...\tools\netcore30* directory.

Put this exe in your environnement path.

Re open visual studio and your error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

A tip for will see this post later:
Open cmd and go inside your project. If you write the error you you can see your error in cmd in more detail.
For example :
`dotnet C:\Users\Adminuser\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.0.6\build\../tools/NetCore22/dotnet-nswag.dll" run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=Debug --verbose`

The reason why I am getting this error is in the nswag.json file
`"isAspNetCore": true` because the line is missing.